# How to have variable and function highlighting in UDL2.1 in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, udl2

In my language, I have variables which are either defined by `dim` or by prefixing it by `@` (implicit variable definition).

I want to add this syntax highlighting to Notepad++, but I think for the `dim`, I'm out of luck. But I tried with `@`, and it's working, but it's highlighting the whole line (for example `@Var.$id` highlights everything, except what I want is everything up to the first `.`).
How could I do this?

## Example

```
@JobListObject = @Node.call("Instantiate", @jblistClass.$id, $self.$id);
```

I want Notepad++ to highlight all of the following:

- `@JobListObject`
- `@Node` (without the `.call`)
- `@jblistClass` (without the `.$id`)
- `$self`
- `$id`
- `call()`

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you choose perl language, it highlights as you want. Have a look in the syntax color file to see how it is done.

Comment: @Toto I think this is done internally, because I checked with "grep -Rin perl *", and I couldn't find anything in these xml files... langs.xml has a few keywords, in functionList.xml there is a perl_function, but it doesn't define how to scan for variables, and stylers are just color settings... So I think it's "baked into Notepad++"

Comment: It seems you're right, too bad :(  May be you'll have more chances asking the Npp forum: https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/